# Java search files from folder

Tags: java, search

I am writing a utility that will search the folder and list files.
The main intention is to find all the files with same name but with diff extensions. For eg: in a given folder we have files that are a.log ,a.jpg,a.clone,b.log, c.log,d.log, d.clone and my output should be only c.log and d.log . My main intention is to find the files which contain extension of .clone  and do not print them in this case files c and d do not have extension of .clone and they should be the output.
I am not able to list the files with the same name but different extensions.

Any advice on how to go about this.

Regards,
Vilas

Comment: We can help you better if we see what code you have written to find and print the files

Comment: How did you try to solve the problem? What causes you the trouble, listing files or comparing strings?

Comment: @Richard  - I have written the following code  'File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
  FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(file);  
  if (listOfFiles.length > 0) {   
   for( int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    name = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    filewoextn = name.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
    if ( name.endsWith(".clone") || name.endsWith(".CLONE")  ) {
     System.out.println("THe name with clone grouping "+ name);
   }else {
    if(name.contains(filewoextn))
    {
    System.out.println("THe name without clone is "+ name);
    fr.write(name);    
    }'

Answer (score 0):

When you list all files in some folder, for example: `File[] files = file.listFiles()`, you can loop through them and check the file names. Here, `file` is actually the folder in which you want to search for your file.

```
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
       if(files[i].getName().startsWith("filename."))
       { 
          do what you want 
       }

    }
```

So all files that starts with `"filename."` will meet the criteria, no matter what comes after the `.` i.e. extension.

Comment: My Code but it is not working.<.br> <code> File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
  FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(file);  
  if (listOfFiles.length > 0) {   
   for( int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    name = listOfFiles[i].getName();filewoextn = name.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
    if ( name.endsWith(".clone") || name.endsWith(".CLONE")  ) {
System.out.println("THe name with clone grouping "+ name);
   }else {
    if(name.contains(filewoextn))
    {
    System.out.println("THe name without clone is "+ name);}}</code> when I am doing that i am getting files without .clone

Comment: That should not be the case as if the folder has the files </br>a.log, a.txt, a.clone, b.log,c.log,c.clone,d.log,d.txt, e.txt,e.log</br> the output is a.txt.b.log,c.log,d.log,d.txt,e.txt which is not correct. </br> The output I am looking at is b.log,d.log,d.txt,e.txt.e.log </br>...what is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7 you can use the [`walkTreeFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) to control how deep you want to go down the tree, and what to do with each file you found (with an appropriate [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html)).

With an `Executor` you can process files without waiting for the search to be finished.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, you should not use `FileVisitor`, `walkTreeFile()` and `File` class as suggested before but you should use the interface `Path` and the method `Files.list(Path dir)` :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
      Path folderWithTheFiles = Paths.get("/my/folder/with/the/files/");

      //list the folder and add files names with a .clone extension in a Set
      Set<String> cloneFilesNames =  Files.list(folderWithTheFiles)
                                     .filter(p->p.toString().endsWith(".clone"))
                                     .map(p -> p.getFileName().toString().split("\\.")[0]).collect(Collectors.toSet());

      //list the folder and filter it with the Set created before
      Files.list(folderWithTheFiles)
           .filter(p->!cloneFilesNames.contains(p.getFileName().toString().split("\\.")[0]))
           .map(Path::getFileName).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

If you want to search deeper in the files tree use `Files.walk(Path dir)` instead of `Files.list(Path dir)`

Comment: This output will print all the files without .clone extension.<br/>My folder will contain files with similar name but different extensions say a.log, a.txt,a.clone, b.log.b.txt,c.log,c.clone, d.log,d.txt <br/> if the folder has a.clone it should not print the other files with the same name like a.log and a.txt <br/>but since the filename "b" does not have extension of .clone it should print b.log,b.txt, c.log, c.txt. How do I search for the files in the folder with similar name but different extensions ?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. If you execute my code with a folder that contains the following files : a.log, a.txt,a.clone, b.log.b.txt,c.log,c.clone, d.log,d.txt

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. If you execute my code with a folder that contains the following files : a.log, a.txt, a.clone, b.log, b.txt, c.log, c.clone, d.log, d.txt
It will print :  b.log, b.txt, d.log, d.txt
Why do you also want to print c.log, c.txt ? the folder contains a c.clone file